# Tikz animated figure coordinates from a vector

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, animations

Is there any possibility to take coordinates in an animated Tikz from a vector?
For example in the code below which I found at (http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/sine-and-cosine-functions-animation/)
instead of increasing the angle via \stepcounter to take the angle from an vector with the value angle=[10,12,15,...] for example. I want to draw an animated quarter car an take the displacement of the masses from vectors I calculated with Matlab. Thank you!

```
    % Sine and Cosine functions animation
%
% Author:
% Efraín Soto Apolinar.
% http://www.aprendematematicas.org/
% 
% This animation helps explain the 
% geometric interpretation of the 
% sine and cosine functions.
%

\documentclass[spanish,10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc} % Language = Spanish
%
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfpagemode=FullScreen}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{animate}
 %
\usetheme{Warsaw} 
\usecolortheme{whale}
 %
 %
 %
 \newcounter{angle}
 \setcounter{angle}{0}
  %
 \begin{document}
 %
 %
 %
 \begin{frame}[fragile]{Sine and Cosine functions}
 \begin{center}
 \begin{animateinline}[loop, poster = first, controls]{30}
 %
 \whiledo{\theangle<359}{
 %
\begin{tikzpicture}
% Axis
\draw[thick,->,blue] (-3,0)--(3,0) node[below] {$x$}; % x axis
\draw[thick,->,blue] (0,-3)--(0,3) node[left] {$y$}; % y axis
\draw[red,thick] (0,0) circle (2.5cm);
\node[red,below] at (2.6,0) {1};
\node[red,above] at (0.1,-2.5) {1};
%
\draw[ultra thick,cyan] (0,0) -- (0,0 |- \theangle:2.5cm); % UpOn x axis
\draw[ultra thick,orange] (0,0) -- (\theangle:2.5cm |- 0,0); % UpOn y axis
%
\draw[densely dotted,orange] (\theangle:2.5cm) -- (\theangle:2.5cm |- 0,0);       % vertical line
\draw[densely dotted,cyan] (\theangle:2.5cm) -- (0,0 |- \theangle:2.5cm); % horizontal line
\draw[ultra thick,red,->,rotate=\theangle] (0,0) -- (2.5,0); 
\node[red,orange,right] at (0,-3.5) 
        {\footnotesize$\cos(\theangle^{\mathrm{o}}) = \pgfmathcos{\theangle}\pgfmathresult$};
\node[red,cyan,right] at (0,-3.1) 
        {\footnotesize$\sin(\theangle^{\mathrm{o}}) = \pgfmathsin{\theangle}\pgfmathresult$};
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\stepcounter{angle}
\ifthenelse{\theangle<359}{
        \newframe
}{
        \end{animateinline}
}
  }
  \end{center}
  \end{frame}
    %
    %
  \end{document}
```

Comment: BTW, don't use `\whiledo` but `\multiframe` for loops with parameters around `animate` frames.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The LaTeX3 "clist" data type can be used as an Array-like container of arbitrary data. A clist variable is initialised from a comma separated list. Individual elements are accessed by index:

```
\documentclass[spanish,10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc} % Language = Spanish
%
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{animate}
%
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usecolortheme{whale}
%
\usepackage{expl3}
%create aliases from clist related functions
\ExplSyntaxOn
\let\clistSet\clist_set:Nn %create clist var from comma separated objects
\let\clistCount\clist_count:N %get number of items in clist
\let\clistItem\clist_item:Nn %get clist item by index (1 <= \clistCount<clist var>)
\ExplSyntaxOff
%
\begin{document}
%
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Sine and Cosine functions}
\begin{center}
\clistSet\myClist{0,10,30,45,50,90,179}

\begin{animateinline}[loop, poster = first, controls]{30}
  \multiframe{\clistCount\myClist}{i=1+1}{  % "i" later be used as index
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    % axes  
    \draw[thick,->,blue] (-3,0)--(3,0) node[below] {$x$}; % x axis
    \draw[thick,->,blue] (0,-3)--(0,3) node[left] {$y$}; % y axis
    \draw[red,thick] (0,0) circle (2.5cm);
    \node[red,below] at (2.6,0) {1};
    \node[red,above] at (0.1,-2.5) {1};
    %
    \draw[ultra thick,cyan] (0,0) -- (0,0 |- \clistItem\myClist{\i}:2.5cm); % UpOn x axis
    \draw[ultra thick,orange] (0,0) -- (\clistItem\myClist{\i}:2.5cm |- 0,0); % UpOn y axis
    %
    \draw[densely dotted,orange] (\clistItem\myClist{\i}:2.5cm) -- (\clistItem\myClist{\i}:2.5cm |- 0,0); % vertical line
    \draw[densely dotted,cyan] (\clistItem\myClist{\i}:2.5cm) -- (0,0 |- \clistItem\myClist{\i}:2.5cm); % horizontal line
    \draw[ultra thick,red,->,rotate=\clistItem\myClist{\i}] (0,0) -- (2.5,0);
    \node[red,orange,right] at (0,-3.5)
            {\footnotesize$\cos(\clistItem\myClist{\i}^{\mathrm{o}}) = \pgfmathcos{\clistItem\myClist{\i}}\pgfmathresult$};
    \node[red,cyan,right] at (0,-3.1)
            {\footnotesize$\sin(\clistItem\myClist{\i}^{\mathrm{o}}) = \pgfmathsin{\clistItem\myClist{\i}}\pgfmathresult$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
\end{animateinline}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
% 
\end{document}
```